# unable to connect arduino mkr1000 with mosquitto broker while using self signed certificate

Tags: ssl, arduino, openssl, mosquitto, self-signed-certificate

I am having a problem connecting to a mqtt server using self signed certificate. I want to connect my mkr1000 securely to my mosquitto MQTT server on ubuntu.  I am generating a CSR on mkr1000 using ARDUINOECCX08CSR example and creating a certificate(.crt),using CA file of ubuntu. Below I am mentioning the process of generating CA,CSR and CRT files for my project.

### PROCEDURE I

#### Ubuntu Machine Steps

## Generate a certificate authority certificate and key in ubuntu

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -extensions v3_ca -keyout ca.key -out ca.crt
      #### passphrase: abcd
```

here i get ca.key and ca.crt, where i used “Ubuntu IP” in common name

Server: 
Generate a server key.

```
 openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048
  #passphrase :abcd
  #I tried both ways with and without -des3
```

Generate a server key without encryption.

```
 openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
```

Generate a certificate signing request to send to the CA.

```
 openssl req -out server.csr -key server.key -new
```

Here I again used “Ubuntu IP” in common Name and I used my subscriber IP( reason, I have no domain name)

Send the CSR to the CA, or sign it with your CA key:

```
 openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 365
```

### Client/Device/MKR1000/ Generating csr

```
    : CSR generated by mkr1000(procedure given below)
```

We are using mkr1000 device for sending sensor data to mosquitto broker as stated above. Libraries which i am using are:

```
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <WiFi101.h> 
#include <ArduinoBearSSL.h>
#include <ArduinoECCX08.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include "arduino_secrets.h"
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2

#For connecting to secure mqtt broker at port no 8883, we are generating ECCX08CSR example from #ArduinoECCX08 library for ECC508 & ECC608 crypto chips, examples in Arduino IDE.##
#Burned code example ECCX08CSR in mkr1000 board 
#On serial monitor we filled the attributes 

#“”””’Serial Monitor”””””””’
ECCX08 Serial Number = 012322619525B27AAF

#Hi there, in order to generate a new CSR for your board, we'll need the following information ...

Country Name (2 letter code) []: 
State or Province Name (full name) []: 
Locality Name (eg, city) []: 
Organization Name (eg, company) []: 
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []: 
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) [012322619525B27AAF]: 54.196.102.5########
#########54.196.102.5 is used as a common name
What slot would you like to use? (0 - 4) [0]: 0
Would you like to generate a new private key? (Y/n) [Y]: y

Here's your CSR, enjoy!

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIHKMHICAQAwEDEOMAwGA1UEAxMFbXlta3IwWTATBgcqhkjOPQIBBggqhkjOPQMBBwNCAARo6lo/
SW6XJ3vWTptpq+xRfiGtVXlfx0H7PRfZqrQCEA6NCkD+DZUQA5hNekMPzveohJscta5PYqAwCQet
TxxhoAAwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIDSAAwRQIgQbwP9SF10O1dVyXsrNhr/HIEP/o2YzRyN7aqeSYaSvQC
IQCaH6+svv9/oV9bfqePi67PrcDLX+PGkAXlTlZlwJD5ZA==
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
“””””””“
```

After this, Copy the CSR and store it in a file in .txt format. 
This file is given to CA for generating a certificate for mkr1000.

And I used again ubuntu IP in Common Name, copy the client.csr content and paste it in new file in UBUNTU with same name client.csr where I run below command to get client.crt

Send the CSR to the CA, or sign it with your CA key:

```
 openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 365
```

IF I compare this UBUNTU generated client.crt file with AWS IoT generated CRT file I found X509 content is missing. To add [X509 content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297139/how-do-you-sign-a-certificate-signing-request-with-your-certification-authority/21340898#21340898) I followed another procedure that one I also tried but still I could not understand why MKR1000 is not connected with Ubuntu while using self signed ssl. Even When I was not using SSL concept It work properly following are the mosquitto sub commands which I ran in Ubuntu Terminal

```
mosquitto_sub  -h “UBUNTU IP” -t “Home” --cafile /home/ubuntu/client.crt -p 8333
```

After getting .crt file generated and signed by CA , We copy the content of the file and paste it in const char SECRET_CERTIFICATE[] variable such as given below

```
 //////////////////////
    const char SECRET_CERTIFICATE[] = R"(-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    MIICZTCCAU0CCQDPGXh/GuZk5zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADB7MQswCQYDVQQGEwJV
    UzENMAsGA1UECAwET2hpbzENMAsGA1UEBwwEb2hpbzEMMAoGA1UECgwDaW90MQsw
    CQYDVQQLDAJDQTEzMDEGA1UEAwwqSXAtMTcyLTMxLTM0LTQzLnVzLWVhc3QtMi5j
    b21wdXRlLmludGVybmFsMB4XDTIwMDEwNTE3MjkwOFoXDTMwMDEwMjE3MjkwOFow
    OTE3MDUGA1UEAxMuZWMyLTMtMTQtMy0xMTIudXMtZWFzdC0yLmNvbXB1dGUuYW1h
    em9uYXdzLmNvbTBZMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHA0IABDDoEdFWMR6ELTDC
    R/8O1kle/6hVEmUA5q+OlSXeUID76FQ5aFG5PkdQcOOI1TfAwBDTTj3Ga+SIKey2
    tXtdkGwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAGNaTcYI2hnUXufV5LWtQPXxBwciPy7/
    apRhd3e2T5j1HuxO9F1uJ5pT5pv+31Cn/d1Aqu/ZmXPMPHRVOl1845cGrm8cYWcj
    ZY1puYQk91t3g9pLHmZbphvL5QeAXPgtZ/saqr3Jch36FvSJrMMy3w+1UXesYFFX
    /lDpwSjSF0F6SqfcezRjp+JFZgl4CHUdXVA1j5K0hwZAm3p8dCdSZABn8SIVdNEc
    jFq4lBxjCoivlTHpQSEeUu30pxyM/CEq0sdxjhIUeq2/74NbKVpGrZJpTRWOxkMG
    lzW+H3txpiuCTedk5FluO4cqUsjlRrlqeC4cZAREVwz11SVhB5Hj8fE=
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    )"
    ////////////////////////
```

After this We upload the code in the MKR1000, the code is given below:

```
'''
    #include <PubSubClient.h>
    #include <WiFi101.h> 
    #include <ArduinoBearSSL.h>
    #include <ArduinoECCX08.h>
    #include <ArduinoJson.h>
    #include <OneWire.h>
    #include <DallasTemperature.h>
    #include "arduino_secrets.h"
    #define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2

    OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS); 
    DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
     String temp;

''' const char* ssid = "XXXXXX";
const char* password = "XXXX";
const char* certificate  = SECRET_CERTIFICATE;
const char* mqtt_server = "";
'''
WiFiClient espClient;
'''BearSSLClient espClient1(espClient);
PubSubClient client(espClient1);
long lastMsg = 0;
char msg[100];
long long int Node_ID = 44;
     int value = 0;
     int i= 0;
    long int tempint;
    void setup_wifi() 
    {  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
'''
  while (!Serial);
   if (!ECCX08.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("No ECCX08 present!");
    while (1);
  }'''
'''ArduinoBearSSL.onGetTime(getTime);
    espClient1.setEccSlot(0, certificate);
    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
'''  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    }
    randomSeed(micros());
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
    Serial.println("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    }
    void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) 
    {
     Serial.print("Message arrived [");
     Serial.print(topic);
     Serial.print("] ");
     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
     {
     Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
     }
     Serial.println();

     // Switch on the LED if an 1 was received as first character
    if ((char)payload[0] == '1') 
    {
    // digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
    // but actually the LED is on; this is because
    // it is active low on the ESP-01)
     }
      else 
    {
    //    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the       voltage HIGH
    }

    }
'''
    void reconnect() 
    {
    // Loop until we're reconnected
       while (!client.connected()) {
       Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Create a random client ID
    String clientId = "Client-";
    clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX);
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(clientId.c_str())) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Once connected, publish an announcement...
      client.publish("accelout", "hello vinit");
      // ... and resubscribe
      client.subscribe("inTopic");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
     }
    }

    void setup() 
   {


    Serial.begin(115200);

    setup_wifi();
    Serial.println("Dallas temp started");
    sensors.begin();  
    client.setServer(mqtt_server, 8883);
     client.setCallback(callback);
                  // Start the serial terminal
     }
    void loop() 
    {

     i=++i;
     if (!client.connected()) 
     {
     reconnect();
     }
      client.loop();

     sensors.requestTemperatures();

     long now = millis();
    StaticJsonDocument<400> doc;
    doc["ID"] = Node_ID;
    doc["RN"] = i;
    doc["Temp"] = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);

    Serial.println();
    serializeJsonPretty(doc,msg);
    Serial.println("Sending message to MQTT topic..");
    Serial.println(msg);
    client.publish("Home",msg);
    unsigned long getTime() 
   {
  // get the current time from the WiFi module  
     return WiFi.getTime();
   }
```

#

After  burning this code I am getting connected to wifi  message on my serial monitor but mkr1000 remains unable to connect to the mqtt server, the code retry to connect to server in every 5 mins.

Comment: Also asked at: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=65829

Comment: Yes, I have already posted there.